# How to use tcpdump using a frequency and channel

Tags: networking, wireless, tcpdump

I am trying to use `tcpdump` monitor mode to monitor wireless traffic. My mac by default looks for traffic in 5 MHz. Is there any way to I can choose the frequency my wireless card does the monitoring in ?

Currently my command is:

```
sudo tcpdump -iI en1
```

Comment: TCP is on another layer than WiFi.

Answer (score 1):

libpcap currently has no APIs for setting the channel, so tcpdump can't set the channel itself.

So you'll have to do it some other way.  Try using the "airport" command, in `/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Apple80211.framework/Versions/Current/Resources/airport`.  Run it with no command-line arguments for a usage message (and pipe it to "more" or "less", as the usage message is *really long*).  The `-c` option should let you set the channel.